# E2E media data encryption methods

Tags: encryption, decryption

To me, security is most important topic for messaging or video conference applications.

I am searching if end to end encryption is possible for group chat or group video conference.

There so some methods like TLS and SRTP (with AES encryption specification ) to encrypt media and signalling data for end to end communication between 2 individuals by changing keys or licenses between them.

As SSL method, public key encrypts media data and on the other endpoint private key decrypts encoded data.

But this method doesn't work fine if 10 or more individuals are in the any chat or conference session since key must be updated with every new user.

What about if there is more than 2 individuals are in the video conference or in a group chat. How can we make end to end encryption and ensure packets can't be monitored as plaintext at server side application for group meetings.

So any person can monitor or sniff data even if captured from server side. I meant if someone hack server side applications he/she can't see plaintext packets due to client side encryption.

I am not asking code. I am just searching technological solution. You can offer me best practices, some kind of solution already implemented before in terms of message flow between endpoints, topology, chiphering&encryption algorithm. I am requesting kind of high or low level design.

I just know open whisper algorithm used in signal app doesn't met totaly my problem.

Off course I will evaluate recommended solution in terms of conference quality and performance and also client side effects.

Best Regards

Comment: Why Signal protocol is not meeting your requirement? Caller can generate a key that is sent together with signalling message which is e2ee. If the receiver answers, P2P encrypted call ensues. To add new member, existing members in the conference negotiates their key with the new joinee.

Comment: Hi Defalt. I read something different abut signal. Can you send me reference link about signal solution ? I should deep dive I think.

Comment: https://signal.org/blog/signal-video-calls-beta/